# In Javascript or any programming language in general, is variable.someMethod() the same as someMethod(variable)?

Tags: javascript

Just something I've been wondering about. If any variable seperated by a dot and followed by a method is the same as that variable being inside the parameter of the method

Comment: Yes, there are some languages that work similar to this, but notice that `variable.someMethod` dispatches on the object while a plain  `someMethod` is looked up in scope (like `variable`) and you may end up calling a different method.

Comment: In some respects there very similar yes, if say you replaced the term variable with say object, then you could say that's what OOP kind of did,  `method(object, params)`  into `object.method(params)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.